# How can I open files within vim's terminal emulator

Tags: vim

Using vim, I use `:term` to open the terminal emulator. After `cd /path/to/project` within the terminal emulator, I have a file called `foo.txt`. If I did `vim foo.txt` to open it as I would in a normal terminal, it would open vim within vim which causes a variety of issues. I see two potential solutions:

- Find some way to open a file in a split from the terminal emulator
- Find some way to change the cwd of vim to the cwd of the terminal emulator.

Does anyone have tips on either solution?

Comment: Tip: don't. Use Vim's built-in file handling features instead. Also, what did you try?

Comment: You can use the server feature to do this, but it requires you to modify the invoking command. Honestly, though, for this particular use-case, I wouldn't. Just jump into normal mode (`<C-w><S-n>`) and open it

Comment: Using Vim's built-in file handling or switching to normal more runs into the issue that Vim's cwd != the cwd of the terminal emulator. This is certainly not the biggest problem, but is still something of an annoyance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside Vim's builtin terminal, do

```
vim --remote foo.txt
```

This assume that your Vim was compile with the `+clientserver` option. You can check with `:version` or `:echo has('clientserver')`.

Comment: Better to specify `servername` like `vim --servername $VIM_SERVERNAME --remote foo.txt`.

Comment: You can specify the server name but this is not necessary if you only have one instance of Vim running.

Answer (score 1):

`vim --remote` works on vim, but neovim compiles without clientserver. [neovim-remote](https://github.com/mhinz/neovim-remote) seems to be an alternative for neovim.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

One would be to get your shell to print the full path of the file that you would like to edit (for example, by using bash's `realpath ./<file_to_edit_goes_here>` command), then exit insert mode, place your cursor over the filepath that was printed, and use `gf` to open the filepath under the cursor (see `:help gf`).

Alternatively, if you are using Neovim, I've written a plugin called [nvim-unception](https://github.com/samjwill/nvim-unception) to open files without nesting Neovim sessions by using Neovim 0.7's built-in RPC functionality.

Answer (score 0):

With Neovim, this seems to work too

```
mvim() {
local fnames_realpath=()
local fnames=( "$@" )
for fname in "${fnames[@]}"; do
    # echo "$fname"
    local fname_realpath=$(realpath "$fname")
    # echo "$fname_realpath"
    fnames_realpath+=("$fname_realpath")
done
if pgrep nvim >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    for fname_realpath in "${fnames_realpath[@]}"; do
        nvim --server $NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS --remote-send "<C-\><C-N>:tabfirst | e $fname_realpath<CR>"
    done
fi
if ! pgrep nvim >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    rm -f "$NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS"
    nvim --listen $NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS "${fnames_realpath[@]}"
fi
}
```

Updated to handle white spaces in the paths and multiple file names, including file names with escaped white spaces.